# Create a fake DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, unit-testing

I am creating an MVC application with EF and currently have used the generic repository pattern, like this one: [Generic Repository Pattern](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/generic-repository-pattern-entity-framework-asp-net-mvc-and-unit-testing-triangle). Everything worked great except for the fact that for each repository a new context was created and working with two or more repositories is needed in my application. As I am using StructureMap I added

```
x.For<IDbContext>().HttpContextScoped().Use(context => new MyContext());
```

where IDbContext has the respective methods and is no longer generic but is passed through the constructor.

The problem comes when I have to test things - I want to create an in memory storage (faster than db, custom, easy to control data), something like a HashTable or HashSet for example. What I cannot figure out is how to make a fake implementation of IDbContext that retreives the data from that HashTable. For reference IDbContext looks like this (only the methods used by the DbContext in the generic repository):

```
    public interface IDbContext : IDisposable
    {
        IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
        DbEntityEntry<TEntity> Entry<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
        int SaveChanges();
    }
```

In the current situation I suppose I have made a major mistake as creating a fake context does not seem to be a regular routine. Any advices on how to improve the architecture of my application and make it more testable are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When I've done this in the past I've generally used a Dictionary to hold my test data something like:

```
public class FakeDb : IDbContext
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Object> _lists = new Dictionary<Type, Object>();
    public List<T> GetList<T>()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        if(!_lists.Contains(type))
        {
            _lists.Add(type, new List<T>());
        }
        return (List<T>)_lists[type];
    }

    ///
}
```

From a broader perspective I've had a lot of success by wrapping my query building logic up into [individual classes rather than repository classes](http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton).